# PowerPoint O365 - v16 Prevent Screen Updating

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am creating shapes on a PowerPoint slide from Excel but it is incredibly slow because each shape is drawn and the screen is updating very slowly. I'm using office 365.

I have seen various posts pointing to the link below - but it appears to be for older versions. Even adding in another line for version 16 isn't doing anything

```
Case "16"
          hWnd = FindWindow("PPTFrameClass", 0&)
```

[PowerPoint VBA Equivalent of Application.ScreenUpdating](http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00033.htm)

Has anyone managed to get this working so I can run Excel VBA, updating PowerPoint without any screen flicker and fast speeds.

Hope there is a solution to this.

Edit: Here is some sample code to run that shows the sort of thing I'm doing. Just need to add reference to **Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library**

```
Option Explicit
Public PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Public PRES As PowerPoint.presentation
Public SLIDE As PowerPoint.SLIDE
Public CANV As PowerPoint.Shape
Public SHP As PowerPoint.Shape

Sub OpenPowerPoint()
  Set PPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
  Set PRES = PPT.Presentations.Add
  PPT.Visible = True
  Set SLIDE = PRES.Slides.Add(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText)
End Sub

Sub CreatePPTShapes()
  If PRES Is Nothing Then OpenPowerPoint
  
  Dim l As Long, t As Long, w As Long, h As Long, x As Long
  Dim size As Long, m As Long, nm As String
  Dim startDate As Long
  startDate = DateSerial(2021, 4, 1)
    
  l = 5
  t = 70
  w = PRES.PageSetup.SlideWidth - 10
  h = PRES.PageSetup.SlideHeight - 75
  
  Set CANV = SLIDE.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, l, t, w, h)

  With CANV
    .Name = "ta_canvas"
    With .Fill
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(240, 240, 240)
      .Transparency = 0
      .Solid
    End With
    With .Line
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      .Transparency = 0.5
      .Weight = 0.25
    End With
  End With
  
  t = t + 5
  w = (w) / 12
  h = 20
  
  For x = 0 To 2
    For m = 0 To 11
      nm = MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", m, startDate)), True)
      
      t = 70 + 7 + (x * 25)
      l = 10 + (w * m)
      
      Dim newPos As Long
      
      Set SHP = SLIDE.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, l, t, w, h)
      With SHP
          .Name = "ta_" & nm
          .Adjustments(1) = 0.25
          .Line.Visible = msoFalse
          .Fill.Visible = True
          .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
          With .TextFrame2
            .TextRange.Characters.Text = nm
            .MarginLeft = 2.8346456693
            .MarginRight = 2.8346456693
            .MarginTop = 0
            .MarginBottom = 0
            .WordWrap = msoFalse
            .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
            With .TextRange.ParagraphFormat
              .FirstLineIndent = 0
              .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
            End With
              .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
              With .TextRange.Font
                .size = 12
                With .Fill
                  .Visible = msoTrue
                  .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                End With
              End With
          End With
      End With
    Next m
  Next x
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to provide help. Scroll about halfway down this page for an alternative method of disabling the screen: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/ppt-vba-macro-how-to-stop-the-screen-updating/63856e51-bce7-4979-8aa7-e0218df30088 Or open the PowerPoint file without opening a window by setting WithWindow to False.

Comment: I've create a sample module that will show the sort of thing I'm doing. Will edit response.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if I switch the view in code to the handout master then the code runs much much quicker. It looks like the screen updating is suspended.

```
ppt.activewindow.viewtype = ppviewhandoutmaster
```

then switch it back at the end to ppViewNormal or whichever your preferred default view.